# Getting an error trying to add contacts to a group from an activity report.

Tags: civireport, error

Getting this error when trying to add contacts to a group from a report.

Table 'childpsy_civicrm.Array' doesn't exist

It's this 'xxx_civicrm.Array' doesn't exist that puzzles me. I'm getting it on another site, but not on others. The CiviCRM Demo site works fine. But that's 5.8.1

Also when viewing a contact, to see what groups they are in....the smart group membership does not work. Using v 5.6.

Can anyone repeat this?

Comment: Normally "Array" is what you get when the code is expecting a variable to be a string but it's an array, so php converts it to the literal string "Array". The backtrace should have the filename and line number - see if you can debug what's actually in the array and it might give a clue.

Answer (score 2):

OK my bad. Upgraded to 5.6.1 and problems disappear.